# Lundi en huit ou lundi en quinze ?

Tags: expressions, indications-de-temps

On est jeudi 6, et je veux parler du lundi 17, qui n'est donc pas le prochain, mais celui d'après.

Pour faire court, j'espérais pouvoir utiliser *lundi en huit* ou *lundi en quinze*. Mais je me rends compte que je ne sais pas lequel il faut utiliser. Même si je choisissais le bon, je me doute qu'il y a des chances que je sois mal compris. (Si on avait été au début de la semaine j'aurais pu choisir sans hésiter.)

En fin de semaine, dois-je utiliser l'un ou l'autre ? Et quelles sont mes chances d'être compris correctement ?

<sub>(Au final, cette fois-ci j'ai opté pour « lundi, pas le prochain mais le suivant, … » mais je trouve ça un peu lourd…)</sub>

Comment: Il y a tellement d'interprétations possibles que la seule solution valide est de donner la date :) Lundi 17 oct.

Comment: Mais… pourquoi forcément se tromper de numéro quand tu peux dire « lundi en 10 » (c'est-à-dire dans une semaine et demi) ? Je ne dirais *lundi en 8* que le dimanche précédent, pour éviter l'« ambiguité » sur *lundi prochain*.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks: Parce que ça n'existe pas. Le but c'est d'être compris.

Comment: Moi, c'est pour être mieux compris que j'emploie des termes qui n'existent pas, mais en l'occurence, j'ai beau ne pas savoir d'où ça vient, et google trouver ça *très* sporadiquement, je suis persuadé que « ça existe », et même indépendamment de moi.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Je comprends « lundi en huit » comme le lundi qui suit le lundi suivant dans ce cas, mais ce n'est pas complètement universel, il y a des gens qui l'appellent « lundi prochain » (je n'ai jamais compris pourquoi). Pour moi, « lundi prochain » est le premier lundi qui commence à partir de ce soir minuit (même s'il y a un certain malaise à l'utiliser le dimanche), « lundi en huit » est le suivant et ainsi de suite. « Lundi en quinze » ne peut pas commencer dans moins de 14 jours.

Je suggère la formule « lundi de la semaine prochaine ». Cette formulation peut être utilisée sans ambiguïté du lundi au vendredi voire le samedi, pour parler d'un jour du lundi au vendredi voire d'un samedi. Malheureusement il n'y a pas de forme courte pour aller plus loin qu'une semaine ; ici, il faut dire quelque chose comme « lundi non pas de la semaine prochaine mais de celle d'après ».

Sinon, on peut toujours dire « lundi dans une semaine et demie » ou « lundi dans dix jours ».

Comment: Cette réponse a le mérite de proposer des formulations qui limitent très fortement les possibilités d'incompréhension, et sans recourir à une date absolue. Visiblement ce n'est pas possible de faire plus court étant donné la variété des interprétations existantes…

Comment: Quand on parle du « lundi de la semaine prochaine » le jeudi 6, je comprends que l’on désigne le lundi 10. En fait, dans le cas du lundi, le « lundi de la semaine prochaine » désigne à mon sens systématiquement « lundi prochain ».

Answer (score 11):

Si tu veux augmenter tes chances d'être compris correctement, utilise simplement « lundi 17 ». C'est clair et sans ambiguïté.

D'ailleurs, il y a même certains personnes qui considèrent que « lundi prochain » est justement non pas le lundi qui vient, mais le prochain. En clair, pour eux, si nous sommes le jeudi 6 « lundi » représente le lundi qui vient, c'est-à-dire le 10, tandis que « lundi prochain » représente le suivant, à savoir le 17. Pour avoir vécu exactement ce problème de communication en couple, je peux t'assurer qu'il est bien réel.

De nouveau, la seule manière de préciser une date sans ambiguïté consiste justement à préciser la date. C'est d'ailleurs d'autant plus important quand le moyen de communication utilisé ne permet pas d'assurer que le texte est lu le même jour qu'il est écrit, parce que le « lundi prochain » d'aujourd'hui n'est pas celui de, disons, lundi prochain. Ça me fait penser aux gens qui écrivent « Tu veux aller au restaurant demain ? » dans un e-mail…

A voir aussi : un sondage sur [quand dans la semaine « jeudi prochain » indique un autre jour](http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/polls/poll0560.html).

Comment: Je suis bien d'accord, mais quand c'est l'intervalle de temps plus que la date précise qui compte, ça m'embête de forcer quelqu'un à faire un calcul. Personnellement, il me faut souvent dix secondes pour trouver quel jour on est (quand j'y arrive).

Answer (score 7):

A priori, cela devrait être :

- lundi prochain => le prochain lundi
- lundi en huit => le prochain lundi après une semaine (comprendre : on ajoute 1 semaine, et de là on prend le premier lundi suivant)
- lundi en quinze => le prochain lundi après deux semaines (comprendre : on ajoute 2 semaines, et de là on prend le premier lundi suivant)

mais j'avoue que je n'ai jamais vraiment rencontré quiconque qui comprenait du premier coup sans ambiguïté ces expressions.

Pour les matheux :

> *jour*_en_huit = *jour_courant* + *n* + 7
>
> où *jour_courant* est le jour de départ,
>   et *n* est le nombre de jours pour aller au jour de référence le plus proche (sans remonter le temps).
>
> Exemple si *jour_courant* est un jeudi
>
> - lundi_en_huit = *jour_courant* + 4 + 7 (4 jours pour aller au lundi le plus proche)
> - jeudi_en_huit = *jour_courant* + 0 + 7 (0 jours pour aller au jeudi le plus proche)

[source](http://villemin.gerard.free.fr/aHumanit/Langue/En_huit.htm)

Comment: Mmm, ta réponse est elle-même ambiguë. Que veut dire « après une semaine » ? Après 7 jours, ou bien après la fin de cette semaine ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : j'ai rajouté l'explication pour les matheux qui explicite sans doute mieux le "après une semaine" (qui se veut le +7 jours :/)

Comment: Une autre ambiguïté (décidément) dans « le jour de référence le plus proche » est-il sous-entendu qu'on parle d'un jour qui suit ? Sinon, le lundi précédent (lundi 3 dans mon cas) est a égalité avec le lundi suivant. Il serait plus proche si on était hier.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : vrai, du coup j'ai creusé un peu plus, et j'ai détaillé quelques explications (le n>=0 manquait)

Comment: Bizarre. Moi qui ai toujours cru que "en huit" marchait pour "dans huit jours. Par ex, on est Jeudi 6, Vendredi prochain, pour moi c'est demain et Vendredi en huit le suivant, dans huit jours. Je ne pensais que cela ne marchait que dans ce cas-là.

Comment: @LudoMC : je dois mal m'exprimer, dans ton cas ça marche, n=1=>vendredi 7 + 7 jours = vendredi 14

Comment: Oui ça marche mais je croyais que ça ne marchait QUE pour ce cas-là, i.e. sans le "+n". J'aurais (encore) appris qqchose :)

Answer (score 1):

Je fais partie de ceux qui utilisent "*prochain*" en lieu et place de "*en huit*". Je suis frontalier de la Belgique, mais j'ignore si la différence est régionale ou non, puisque le nombre d'interprétations varie dans mon entourage aussi.

Pour ceux que ça surprend, une explication possible est que dans mon cas, j'utilise "ce Lundi" pour celui qui suit immédiatement la date courante, et donc le "prochain Lundi" est le suivant sur la liste.

A noter que dans les pays anglo-saxons, c'est le même principe qui s'applique : "*next Friday*" n'est **pas** le "*Vendredi suivant*", mais le "*Vendredi en huit*". On utilise "*this Friday*" pour celui qui arrive immédiatement.

Comment: Si, un mardi, tu me parles de « ce lundi » je pense que tu me parles de la veille. Et je suis frontalier également. Lundi prochain, pas d’ambiguité (même si je l’éviterai le dimanche).

Answer (score 1):

J'ai toujours utilisé ce mot pour signifier:
S'il est lundi aujourd'hui, *jeudi en huit* est le jeudi après le plus proche jeudi (sans remonter dans le temps).

Ceci est confirmé par ce [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_huit) et (à mon avis indirectement) par ce [dictionnaire](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.com/en%20huit/fr-fr/). Le dictionnaire sur TV5.org suggère la même explication que le dictionnaire que je viens de référencer.

Answer (score 1):

J'ai l'impression que c'est la même logique que pour la question [Pourquoi huit ou quinze jours pour une ou deux semaines ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2758/pourquoi-huit-ou-quinze-jours-pour-une-ou-deux-semaines?noredirect=1&lq=1) (passionnant à lire, au demeurant) : par exemple, si on est jeudi, *lundi prochain* tombe dans 4 jours, tandis que *lundi en huit* signifie que j'avance d'une semaine en pensée (je me situe jeudi prochain), et à ce moment-là le *lundi en huit* d'aujourd'hui sera devenu le *prochain lundi*.

**Lundi en quinze** serait donc la même explication, avec un écart de deux semaines au lieu d'une.

Au-delà, ça devient vraiment compliqué et il vaut mieux donner la date.

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour,

Bordelais marié à une Tourangelle, elle vient de répondre (pour un rendez-vous mardi trente, nous sommes lundi 22 octobre) à mon "Mardi en huit !" -> "Donne-moi plutôt la date !".

Le français étant né à Villers-Cotterêts et s'étant perfectionné dans les châteaux de la Loire, autour de Tours, il semble donc effectivement qu'au XXIème siècle, les chiffres (indiens) aient la préséance sur les mots (latins) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Définition: prochain:

Qui est le premier à se présenter, dans l'espace ou le temps : S'arrêter à la prochaine station-service.

Se dit de la date ou de la période qui est la première à survenir par rapport au moment où l'on parle : Le mois prochain, nous déménageons.

Donc lundi en huit n'est pas le prochain mais le suivant, et lundi en 15 celui encore après.

Pour moi pas d’ambiguïté, que l'on soit lundi ou dimanche, lundi prochain est celui de la semaine suivante, lundi en huit le suivant, lundi en quinze encore celui qui suit, etc. Pas sûr qu'on dise lundi en 21 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Vous vous compliquez la vie pour rien ; l'expression est simple :

- lundi prochain = lundi qui vient,
- lundi en 8 = lundi qui vient + 7 jours
- lundi en 15 = lundi qui vient + 14 jours.

Answer (score 0):

Moi j'utilise *« ce lundi »* pour parler de celui le plus proche QUE L'ON VIENT DE VIVRE, qui est déjà arrivé. *« Le Lundi qui arrive »* pour celui qui arrivera le premier, et *« le lundi suivant »* pour celui encore après. Les autres je les connais pas bien je préfère ne pas parler d'eux sans savoir.