# Pourquoi huit ou quinze jours pour une ou deux semaines?

Tags: expressions, étymologie, indications-de-temps

Il y a quelques temps, un de mes professeurs, s'adressant au groupe : « Nous avons vu il y a quinze jours... ». Or, les cours sont donnés la même journée chaque semaine.

D'où vient cette expression? Pourquoi utilise-t-on quinze ou huit jours pour faire référence à la même journée d'une autre semaine? Y a-t-il quelque chose de similaire pour trois semaines?

Je sais que « quinze » dérive dans ce cas de « quinzaine », mais il y a là une notion d'approximation que le chiffre en tant que tel ne possède pas. Est-ce par pure paresse; il est plus facile de dire quinze que quinzaine ou quatorze? Si tel est le cas, pourquoi huit et non sept?

Question connexe : [Lundi en huit ou lundi en quinze?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1398/lundi-en-huit-ou-lundi-en-quinze)

Comment: Au Mexique, c'est pareil. Ils disent « depuis aujourd'hui en huit » pour dire « depuis une semaine. » En outre, ils disent aussi : « chaque huit jours » pour dire hebdomadaire. Je pense que la raison vient de la période de la francisation de Maximiliano de Habsburgo.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

L'expression est un héritage des Romains qui divisaient les mois (déjà pour eux de 30 ou 31 jours) en quatre périodes inégales (c'est exprès que je n'emploie pas le mot « semaine »).
Pour un mois de trente jours on avait ainsi une période de huit jours suivie d'une période de sept jours, le tout répété deux fois.
Une quinzaine est la durée d'une période de huit jours suivi d'une période de sept jours.

De la même façon on emploie « huitaine » pour signifier « une semaine ».  En France les expressions *sous huitaine* et *sous quinzaine* ont acquis au Moyen-Âge un sens juridique qui est encore employé.

---

Edit (20 juin)
En italien on dit *quindicina* (quizaine) pour exprimer une période de deux semaines.  Ce qui semble accréditer l'origine romaine de l'expression.

Comment: La prise en compte de cet usage induit la notion de *jour franc* définie juridiquement (http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/R1008.xhtml)

Comment: Very interesting! Always wondered this.

Comment: Explication souvent lue mais peu vraisemblable. Le calendrier Julien avait un intervalle fixe de 8 jours, les nundinaes. Or ce mot est formé à partir de novem dies (neuf jours) car les Romains comptaient le jour en cours dans l'intervalle de temps (ex:. Pour jusqu'à demain soir ils comptaient 2 jours). Quand les semaines de 7 jours furent introduites au IVe siècle dans le calendrier Julien, un délai de 7 jour francs devint 8 jours, 2 semaines 15 jours. Les Anglais ont résolu le problème en donnant les noms sennight (7 nuits) et fortnight (14 nuits) pour les mêmes durées. Astuce !

Answer (score 11):

Vraisemblablement la même origine que le troisième jour pour la résurrection du Christ (mort un vendredi et ressuscité le dimanche), on compte le jour où on parle, même si ce n'est pas l'usage le plus courant.

Il est des cas où un comportement similaire est la norme. La première année d'un enfant va de sa naissance à son premier anniversaire, le premier siècle de notre ère va de l'an 1 à l'an 100, etc...

Comment: voici une discussion sur wordforum qui est plus ou moins d'accord avec cette théorie: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=840441

Mon souvenir (très lointain) de mes cours de latin au lycée est que les romains comptaient le jour où on parle de façon systématique.  La quinzaine de Pâques ou les 40 jours de Carême se comptent de façon similaire.

Comment: @SamuelLisi: En effet, par exemple les Romains désignaient la période de 8 jours entre deux jours de marché à Rome par [nundinaes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nundines) (novem dies, 9 jours). La raison est qu'ils incluaient [hodie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hodie#la) en plus des jours francs à venir jusqu'au marché suivant.