# How do you translate "on Friday week" or "a week on Friday" or "Friday after next"?

Tags: indications-de-temps

How do you translate "on Friday week" or "a week on Friday" or "Friday after next"? For example, "I'll see you [one of those phrases]"?

Answer (score 5):

On se verra vendredi **en huit**. *voir ce [lien](http://villemin.gerard.free.fr/aHumanit/Langue/En_huit.htm)*

Some people say sometimes "pas le prochain, l'autre"; they use this form either as a replacement of the concise form either as a confirmation of "en huit" as they feel they haven't been understood.

On se verra vendredi **en huit**, pas le prochain, l'autre.

Comment: Voir aussi https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1398/lundi-en-huit-ou-lundi-en-quinze et https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2758/pourquoi-huit-ou-quinze-jours-pour-une-ou-deux-semaines