# Quand emploie-t-on l’article défini (Le/La) devant le mot « weekend » ou « semaine »

Tags: articles, articles-definis

D’après ce que l’on m’a expliqué, on utilise « le » quand on parle de tous les samedis (par exemple), et on l’enlève quand on parle d’un jour précis, comme samedi dernier ou samedi prochain. Alors, dit-on « le week-end dernier » ou tout simplement « week-end dernier », et par rapport à « semaine » et d’autres mots de ce genre comme « mois »?

Merci d’avance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'absence d'article est possible avec le nom d'un jour de semaine mais *weekend* ne correspond pas à cette définition, comprenant deux jours successifs (voire plus si prolongé).

Pour distinguer les deux cas, on dira **le weekend** s'il s'agit des weekends en général, **ce weekend** pour parler du plus proche, ou alors **le weekend dernier** / **le weekend prochain** s'il y a besoin de préciser duquel il s'agit.

Voir aussi: [Lundi en huit ou lundi en quinze ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1398/lundi-en-huit-ou-lundi-en-quinze) pour les interprétations parfois discordantes de **prochain** quand il s'applique à un jour.

Comment: Petite remarque en passant, si on est mardi et que l'on dit "on se voit samedi prochain", certaines personnes comprennent le samedi de cette semaine, et d'autres comprennent samedi de la semaine prochaine.

Comment: Ca marche pour les jours et le week-end, mais pas pour les mois : "Les week-ends c'est grasse matinée !", "Le mardi (ou les mardis) j'ai cours de natation", "Ce mercredi j'ai un entretien". Par contre on ne diras pas "Janvier, je vais aux sports d'hiver" mais plutôt "Tous les mois de janvier, je vais aux sports d'hiver". Pour semaine non plus, on ne dit pas "Les semaines je vais à la piscine", mais bien : "Chaque semaine (ou toutes les semaines) je vais à la piscine" (peu importe quel est le jour, c'est ici le fait d'y aller de façon hebdomadaire qui est mis en évidence).

Comment: @Ben Oui, cette interprétation curieuse de *prochain* a déjà été évoquée plusieurs fois ici. Ex. : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1398/lundi-en-huit-ou-lundi-en-quinze. Si on parle d'un mois en général, on se passe de préposition: *Janvier, c'est un bon mois pour aller skier*. Ca n'est pas possible pour une saison: *Printemps, c'est une bonne saison pour jardiner*